# How to save a PDF using Graphics.DrawString in C#?

Tags: c#, pdf-generation

I have the  `Graphics.DrawString` method for Print Preview.

Now I would like to use the same code to save it as a PDF. I have a Form, I have created a printprewiew and I would like  to save as it is in printPrview to pdf.

Is it posible to do this?

Comment: How you create the PDF file is going to depend entirely on what library you use to generate it. As you haven't specified one, your question is difficult to answer. Have you actually done any research into creating PDF files?

Comment: Including more details in your question may help members answer it.

Comment: I saw some use iTextSharp but I don't know how to start

Comment: You don't know how to start what?

Comment: how to start creating a pdf file.

Comment: This is going to be kind of like a magician giving away the secret to all his tricks and I'm sure a lot of developers are going to be really upset when I give away the magic, but here's how you get started: http://www.google.com

Comment: Lol i know this one but didn't find one I could use or would help me

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution this may help you, but it requires to download and install "CutePDF Writer". CutePDF Writer is free software. You can download it from there official website.

```
           PrintDialog pDia = New PrintDialog()
           PrinterSettings ps = New PrinterSettings()

            pDia.Document = PrintDocument1
            pDia.Document.DocumentName = "Your File Name"

            ps.PrinterName = item.ToString()
            ps.PrintToFile = False

            //Create folder inside Bin folder to save PDFs
           String strReportBackupPath = "C:\\"

            String strFilePath  = strReportBackupPath & "\\" & pDia.Document.DocumentName & ".pdf"
            //To avoid the replace dialog of cutePDF - To save new file if have same name
            ps.PrintFileName = strFilePath 
            PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings = ps
            PrintDocument1.Print()
```

but it will show you save as dialog to save the file to pdf.